# Do you know of any indecomposable ring that has no isolated elements and is neither reversible, nor integral, nor nilpotent, nor unitary?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a non commutative ring. We will say that an element of $R$ is isolated if it is zero divisor and nothing nonzero annihilates it at the same time on both sides.
Note that there are many classes of rings that do not contain isolated elements.

$\bullet$ If  $R$ is an integral ring, it does not contain isolated elements.

$\bullet$ If  $R$ is a nilpotent ring,  it does not contain isolated elements.

$\bullet$ If $R$ is a reversible ring, it does not contain isolated elements.

$\bullet$ If $R$ is a finite unital ring, it does not contain isolated elements.

Do you know of any indecomposable ring that has no isolated elements and is neither reversible, nor integral, nor nilpotent, nor unitary?

Comment: Please write the actual question inside the question body, not just in the title. Also, what is $L$?

Comment: Hello: if I am not mistaken, you have posted this question before. In general, one should not delete questions and repost them. Instead, use the edit button. The act of editing the question bumps it to the top of the list.   There is no need to delete and repost, which is an activity that is frowned upon.  If I am in error about the claim you've posted this before, my apologies.

Comment: @GrauRibas: If $R$ is an associative ring, $Z(R)$ stands for the center of the ring $R$ and $Z(R)^*$ is the set of reversible elements from $Z(R)$, then every element from $Z(R)^*$ is isolated. Moreover, each element of $R^*$ is isolated.
If I am wrong, please formulate your question more precisely, in particular, give explanation of all notations and definition of all concepts.

Comment: @kabenyuk Sorry, I hope that after my edition my question is better understood,

Comment: The definition of isolated seems the same as being a non zero divisor... any reference for such definition ?

Comment: @InfiniteLooper It doesn't say it's a zero divisor, it says that nothing nonzero annihilates it _at the same time on both sides_.  There can still be nonzero $z, z'$ such that $zx=0=xz'$. In his earlier version of the question he expressed it as the intersection of the right and left annihilator as being trivial

Comment: Indeed. Emphasis on $R$ being non commutative may be useful or maybe i am just a too much commutative guy